# Is it too late to get a refund for the DAOs

Tags: the-dao, thedao-refund

I have some DAOs and some DAO_extraBalance. Is it too late to get a refund?
If not, what is an easy way to get the refund. I do not have mist or the ethereum wallet, I just have a JSON

Comment: DAO->ETH and DAO->ETH extraBalance have no time limits. DAO->ETC has a time limit at the end of Feb 2017. But it is best to convert ASAP. If you don't have Ethereum Wallet / Mist, use MyEtherWallet - latest news at [Announcing MyEtherWallet v3.4: The Node Switcher](https://np.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5lqx90/announcing_myetherwallet_v34_the_node_switcher/).

Comment: See also [DAO Token Holders, Come Claim Your Money! Updated!](https://medium.com/curator-multisig-phf-official-channel/dao-token-holders-come-claim-your-money-b428f186572a#.s2rp0qps2), [The DAO ExtraBalWithdraw Contract Has Now Been Topped Up](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/532523/the_dao_extrabalwithdraw_contract_has_now_been/).